# Как разместить объект conditions вне функции но чтобы код отрабатывал так же

Tags: javascript, массивы, функции, объекты

```
const passes = [ 'abcdj', 'asfalseiruqwo', 'bhhkkbbjjjb' ];
//conditions = {...}

function conditionValidate(conditionProp) {
    const validator = () => passes.map( pass => pass.split('').filter( el => el === conditionProp ? el : false).length);

    return validator().filter( el => {
        const conditions = { 'a': ( el > 0 && el < 5 ), 'z': ( el > 1 && el < 5), 'b': ( el > 2 && el < 7)};
        if (conditions[conditionProp]) return el;
    }).length;
}

console.log(conditionValidate('a'), conditionValidate('z'), conditionValidate('b'));
```

Comment: Вместо дублирования заголовка в тексте вопроса, лучше дополнить вопрос подробностями (указать трудности возникшие при попытке решения задачи, и/или более точно описать проблему). Отредактировать вопрос можно нажатием текстовой кнопки "[Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1305985/edit)" под ним.

Comment: Вопрос закрыт, спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если можно изменить структуру `conditions`, тогда возможен такой вариант (немного переформатировал остальной код, чтобы было меньше длинных строк и горизонтальной прокрутки):

```js
const passes = [ 'abcdj', 'asfalseiruqwo', 'bhhkkbbjjjb' ];

const conditions = {
  'a': el => ( el > 0 && el < 5 ),
  'z': el => ( el > 1 && el < 5),
  'b': el => ( el > 2 && el < 7),
};

function conditionValidate(conditionProp) {
    const validator = () => passes
      .map(
        pass => pass
                  .split('')
                  .filter( el => el === conditionProp ? el : false)
                  .length
      );

    return validator().filter( el => {
        if (conditions[conditionProp](el)) return el;
    }).length;
}

console.log(
  conditionValidate('a'),
  conditionValidate('z'),
  conditionValidate('b')
);
```

Но вообще код кажется довольно таинственным. Лучше не привыкать к такой загадочной мистике)

Comment: Спасибо большое :**

Comment: Не могу пока отзывы людям давать)